# how to programatically set nginx configuration directives to nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, shell-scripting

I am trying to make a shell script to auto install a web app and the script needs to set `client_max_body_size` to a bigger size, at some point.

Of course, it's possible to set this directive using nano but this is not what I am looking for. The script should be able to se the value for this directive in http section by itself.

---

The script needs to set mentioned directive in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

I have got this example in nginx docs, but I don't know how to modify this to my use-case:

> nginx -g "pid /var/run/nginx.pid; worker_processes `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`;"

Comment: Can you simply copy the required config file over?

Comment: yes, this is a possibility but I was wondering if the user has some directives /etc/nginx/nginx.conf that it needs to use. @Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many distributions, there is a `include conf.d/*.conf` line in `nginx.conf` `http` section.

So, the script can create a file in `conf.d` directory with `.conf` extension and the reload nginx configuration.